# How to meet this need? genericity?inheritance?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, textview, widget

there are many sensors(gps/temperature/brightness) listened by SensorManager.

```
class Sensor{

 public Sensor getInstance(){
  
 }
 public register(int id,Listener listener){
 }
 public unRegister(Listener listener){
 }
 
 public interface Listener{
  void onDataChange(int id, int value);
 }

}
```

I want to use different widgets to display different sensors.
like this:

```
    abstract class View1 extends TextView{
      abstract int getSensorId();
      abstract void onValueChange(int value);
      public void onAttachToWindow(){
        Sensor.getInstance.register(id,listener);
      }
    
      public void onDetachFromWindow() {
         Sensor.getInstance.unRegister(listener);
      }
      listener = new Listener(){
          void onDataChange(int id, int value){
             onValueChange(value);
          }
      }
    
   }




    abstract class View2 extends Button{
      abstract int getSensorId();
      abstract void onValueChange(int value);
      public void onAttachToWindow(){
        Sensor.getInstance.register(id,listener);
      }
    
      public void onDetachFromWindow() {
         Sensor.getInstance.unRegister(listener);
      }
      listener = new Listener(){
          void onDataChange(int id, int value){
             onValueChange(value);
          }
      }
    
   }



  abstract class View3 extends ImageView{
      abstract int getSensorId();
      abstract void onValueChange(int value);
      public void onAttachToWindow(){
        Sensor.getInstance.register(id,listener);
      }
    
      public void onDetachFromWindow() {
         Sensor.getInstance.unRegister(listener);
      }
      listener = new Listener(){
          void onDataChange(int id, int value){
             onValueChange(value);
          }
      }
    
   }


 abstract class View4 extends LinearLayout {
      abstract int getSensorId();
      abstract void onValueChange(int value);
      public void onAttachToWindow(){
        Sensor.getInstance.register(id,listener);
      }
    
      public void onDetachFromWindow() {
         Sensor.getInstance.unRegister(listener);
      }
      listener = new Listener(){
          void onDataChange(int id, int value){
             onValueChange(value);
          }
      }
    
   }



 abstract class View5 extends RelativeLayout{
      abstract int getSensorId();
      abstract void onValueChange(int value);
      public void onAttachToWindow(){
        Sensor.getInstance.register(id,listener);
      }
    
      public void onDetachFromWindow() {
         Sensor.getInstance.unRegister(listener);
      }
      listener = new Listener(){
          void onDataChange(int id, int value){
             onValueChange(value);
          }
      }
    
   }
```

The problem is too many widget.
I figured out a solvent.(which failed to compile)

```
abstract AbsView<T extends View> extends T{
     abstract int getSensorId();
      abstract void onValueChange(int value);
      public void onAttachToWindow(){
        Sensor.getInstance.register(id,listener);
      }
    
      public void onDetachFromWindow() {
         Sensor.getInstance.unRegister(listener);
      }
      listener = new Listener(){
          void onDataChange(int id, int value){
             onValueChange(value);
          }
      }

  }
```

expecting i can use it like this

```
class View1 extends AbsView<TextView>{
      int getSensorId(){
        return gpsId;
      }

     void onValueChange(int value){
        setText("xxxx");
     }
}

class View2 extends AbsView<ImageView>{
      int getSensorId(){
        return gpsId;
      }

     void onValueChange(int value){
        setImage(xxx);
     }
}

class View3 extends AbsView<LinearLayout>{
      int getSensorId(){
        return gpsId;
      }

     void onValueChange(int value){
        addView(xxx);
     }
}
```

Them the compiler told me I can't do this.
So,is there any more elegant ways to accomplish it?

Comment: do you actually need to be extending from textView and button here ?

Comment: yes, there are numerous fields to display, they use a same appearance